# Проблема с отправкой post запроса в react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, axios

Я пытаюсь отправить данные в firebase

**Кнопка**

```
<Button type='submit' onSubmit={this.props.submitHandler}>Отправить</Button>
```

**MapDispatchToProps**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    submitHandler: (e) => {dispatch({type:'SUBMIT'})},
   ...
});
```

**Reducer**

```
case 'SUBMIT':
 let uid = 'test';
 const data = {
 ...
 };
  axios.post(`https://test-base.firebaseio.com/users/${uid}.json`, data)
```

Если я делаю тоже самое внутри компонента (добавляя e.preventDefault()), запрос уходит успешно. Как я понял, проблема именно в этом - что я не отменяю действие по умолчанию, но как его можно отменить внутри reducer-а?

Comment: Вам похоже нужно начать с [основ](https://redux.js.org/glossary#reducer): _Do not put API calls into reducers._ reducer работает только с объектом состояния. никаких запросов там быть не должно!

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, как лучше решить эту задачу? Может описать логику в самом компоненте?

Comment: Можно и в самом компоненте. Но лучше оформить все запросы к API в виде функций-оберток и вынести их в отдельную папку. И потом вызывать из компонента соотв-ую функцию. `dispatch`-ить `action` нужно только по завершению запроса.

Comment: Используйте middleware в redux